# Show the information of SDO_GEOMETRY (CENTROID)

Tags: database, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spatial

I'm working with a spatial database of Oracle but I have some troubles.
I'm doing some procedures using geometric subprograms like `SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH` that returns a number but when I use others geometric subprograms like `SDO_GEOM.CENTROID` I don't know how to show the information because of this return an `SDO_OBJECT`.

I'm new to the Spatial Oracle subprograms so I appreciate your help.

This is the code where I'm working on it:

```
PROCEDURE centroId(pnombre IN VARCHAR2) IS
    geomEntrada SDO_GEOMETRY;
    dist VARCHAR2(100);
    tupla caceres%ROWTYPE;
    dim SDO_DIM_ARRAY;
    -- Cursor para recuperar los barrios
    CURSOR cursor_barrio IS 
      SELECT *
      FROM caceres
      WHERE tipo = 'Barrio';

  BEGIN

    -- Recuperar la geometria del parametro de entrada
    SELECT Geom INTO geomEntrada
    FROM Caceres
    WHERE Nombre = pnombre;

    -- Obtener dim
    SELECT DIMINFO INTO dim
    FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
    WHERE table_name='CACERES'; --Ojo, CACERES en mayúsculas

    -- Recorrer todos los barrios
    OPEN cursor_barrio;
    LOOP
      FETCH cursor_barrio INTO tupla;
      EXIT WHEN cursor_barrio%NOTFOUND;

      --SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH
      dist := SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(geomEntrada,dim);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pnombre||' have this center: ' || dist);

  END centroId;
```

What I'm doing wrong?
How can I show the information? Could be using st_asText?

Answer (score 0):

SDO GEOMETRY is indeed a complex subject. If you're going to do much with it I suggest a serious reading of Oracle's "Spatial User's Guide and Reference" (for your version of Oracle), maybe a couple times.

You asked how to get information out of the Object, but without specifying the target information. I'll have to accept the logic presented and assume it collects the necessary data. That is except for the **dist** definition and/or it's assignment.  The function SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID returns not a sring, but an SDO_GEOMETRY. And within it another object an SDO_POINT_TYPE which itself is composed of 3 numbers; (x, y, z). In geographic or geospatial data corresponds to longitude, latitude, altitude.

There is nothing special about accessing these values, just use he standard dot (.) notation. So here:

```
declare 
  dest sdo_geometry; 
  .
  .
  .
  dest := sdo_geom.sdo_centroid(geomEntrada,dim);
  dbms_output.put_line(pnombre||' have this center: ' 
                     || "longitude=' || to_char(l_centroid.sdo_point.x)
                     || " latitude=' || to_char(l_centroid.sdo_point.y) 
                     );
```

Accessing the information from SDO types are no different than accessing information from any other Oracle object: you need to know the definition and use the dot (.) notation at each level.

BTW: The above reference manual contains these definitions.

```
CREATE TYPE sdo_geometry AS OBJECT (
 SDO_GTYPE NUMBER, 
 SDO_SRID NUMBER,
 SDO_POINT SDO_POINT_TYPE,
 SDO_ELEM_INFO MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY,
 SDO_ORDINATES MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY);

CREATE TYPE sdo_point_type AS OBJECT (
   X NUMBER,
   Y NUMBER,
   Z NUMBER);
```